# Table width scrolling site left and right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm stumped as to what is causing this. I have duplicate sites but in one of them, I have a table that is causing my site to scroll left and right.

Using Web Developer Toolbar, I am able to outline the table which shows the table being pushed out. See Figure 1.

[image]

And here's the link...http://goo.gl/0r2if
Furthermore, I have tried everything in Firebug to see if I can force that table to be smaller without any joy.

[image]
I've also compared it to the other site which is just a replica of this one cannot seem to find a difference.

I've also searched to see if I can find something about odd 100% widths in tables and nothing I've tried has worked either.

No doubt it is going to be a simple mistake but I think I just need some fresh eyes on this please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The continue shopping link has css value `width: 1083px;`

```
<a class="continue-shopping" href="/products/">Continue shopping</a>

#shoppingcartcontents a.continue-shopping {
    color: #9F1B32;
    display: block;
    font: 15px 'another_typewriterregular',arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 1083px;
}
```

It's inside the last row of the shopping cart table, so that's what's causing it. Remove the width and it's fixed.

Comment: indeed i'v just spotted that as well

Comment: Thanks Korijn! I knew it was going to an oversite!